# Why is the java library coded so unreadable?

Tags: java, performance

Sometimes when I get to check what a java.util class does, I see stuff like this:

```
final Node<K,V> getNode(int hash, Object key) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> first, e; int n; K k;
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null) {
        if (first.hash == hash && // always check first node
            ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return first;
        if ((e = first.next) != null) {
            if (first instanceof TreeNode)
                return ((TreeNode<K,V>)first).getTreeNode(hash, key);
            do {
                if (e.hash == hash &&
                    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                    return e;
            } while ((e = e.next) != null);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Or this for example:

```
if ((next = (current = e).next) == null && (t = table) != null) {
    do {} while (index < t.length && (next = t[index++]) == null);
}
```

They tend to use a lot assigning a variable in the same line they check its value, and other stuff that makes the code hard to read.

I mean, in order to read and understand this, I have to read it several times and separate stuff in my mind. **But if this would have been coded differently, I don't think it would be that hard to understand it.**

Is this because of performance? If yes, should I do the same when writing code? Is it something common?

Comment: This question seems to be soliciting opinions and inviting speculation (unless Java library authors are around to answer it), and therefore not a good fit for Stackoverflow. Consider revising it.

Comment: It ain't *that* bad! Have a look at some of the C++ standard library source: *that* is a challenging bedtime read. Besides, you're supposed to read the *documentation*, not the code.

Comment: I think the question here is: "Is assign and check" an efficient operation but the comment about readability make it off topic for SO.

Comment: Being verbose just increases file size... whats not to understand here?

Comment: The standard library **API is used by many**. The standard library **implementation is maintained by few**. For a heavily used library, performance may outweigh readability. Tricks that play to the strengths of the compiler may be warranted.

Comment: @AndyThomas ok, but I want to know how would this affect the perfomance. As other said, it makes no difference

Comment: @PabloMatiasGomez - Asking about the utility of including an assignment in a larger expression would be a valid question for this site. The presumption that it "makes no difference" could be tested *per compiler* by time or bytecode.

Answer (score 3):

I'd argue that the readability of this code is actually not bad. Once you get used to certain stylistic tricks (like when you mentioned an assignment of a variable in the same line you check a conditional), reading code like this comes more naturally.

Also, some Java library functions are hard to understand just because of the algorithm they are implementing. For example, I doubt anybody would be able to understand an efficient sorting function in one read. I'd say that most interesting code needs you to read it multiple times to understand it.

As for efficiency, I doubt it makes a difference. It usually compiles down to the same instructions anyway.